# Jenkins Docker image - permission problems when only putting the `jobs` folder into a named volume

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-volume

I'm running Jenkins in a Docker container by extending [the official image](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker) in my own `Dockerfile`.

The top section of that page recommends to put the whole `$JENKINS_HOME` folder into a named volume in order to have changes made via the UI persist over container restarts and re-creations.

However, I do not want the whole `$JENKINS_HOME` folder to be part of this volume but only the `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs` folder. The reasons for this are:

- Plugins are set up by the `install_plugins.sh` script from the base image during the image build process [as documented here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker#preinstalling-plugins).
- All other configuration will be created from scratch on each image build by the [configuration-as-code plugin](https://jenkins.io/projects/jcasc/).
- Only the jobs are not re-created from scratch on each image build and consequently should persist in a named volume.

In consequence I start the Jenkins container like this:

```
docker run \
    -p 8080:8080 \
    -p 50000:50000 \
    -v jenkins-jobs:/var/jenkins_home/jobs \
    my-custom-jenkins-image
```

The container now fails to properly start with `permission denied` errors in the logs. Checking the permissions inside `$JENKINS_HOME` via `docker exec container_name_or_id ls -ahl /var/jenkins_home` shows that `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs` is now owned by `root` instead of the `jenkins` user who owns all other files and subdirectories there and `$JENKINS_HOME` itself.

Interestingly enough, when putting the whole `$JENKINS_HOME` folder into a named volume than all files and subfolders in it will be correctly owned by the `jenkins` user.

How could I only put the `jobs` folder into a named volume and make sure that it belongs to the `jenkins` user inside of the container?

**edit:**
My `Dockerfile` stripped down to the minimum looks like this. However, I don't suspect any of this to be the root cause since the same thing happens when running the `jenkins/jenkins:lts` stock image, as in:

```
docker run \
    -p 8080:8080 \
    -p 50000:50000 \
    -v jenkins-jobs:/var/jenkins_home/jobs \
    jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

The `Dockerfile` of the base image can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/Dockerfile).

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts

USER root

# install plugins
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt

# Configuration as code plugin
# The configuration file must be stored outside of the Jenkins home directory
# because this is mounted as a volume - consequently, changes to the file in
# the image would not make it into the container which would override it with
# the previous version from the volume.
ENV CASC_JENKINS_CONFIG=/run/jenkins.yaml
COPY --chown=jenkins:jenkins jenkins.yaml /run/jenkins.yaml

# don't run plugin and admin user setup wizard at first run
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false"

USER jenkins
```

Comment: Could you please share your Dockerfile

Comment: Switch to user "jenkins" at the end of your dockerfile. (USER jenkins) and start container with "-u jenkins".

Comment: Added my `Dockerfile`, see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Terrible work-around that fixes the problem until there is a better solution:

1. Add the following lines to the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts

USER root

# Install additional tools and plugins, set up configuration etc.

# We need the gosu tool to step down from the root user to an unprivileged
# user as part of the entrypoint script.
# See further: https://github.com/tianon/gosu
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install gosu

# Note that we stay the root user and do not step down to the jenkins user yet.
COPY fix_volume_ownership.sh /usr/local/bin/fix_volume_ownership.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "--", "/usr/local/bin/fix_volume_ownership.sh"]
```

Create `fix_volume_ownership.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script is run by the root user in order to have the privileges to change
# ownership of the jobs directory. The jobs directory is mounted as a named
# volume and otherwise is owned by the root user so that the jenkins user
# cannot write into it.
#
# "gosu" finally steps down from the root user to the jenkins user since we
# do not want to run the Jenkins process with root privileges.
#
# /usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh is the original entrypoint script from the base image.

chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/jenkins_home/jobs
gosu jenkins /usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh
```

Now, `docker exec container_name_or_id ls -ahl /var/jenkins_home` will show that the `jobs` subfolder is correctly owned by the `jenkins` user. In addition, `docker exec container_name_or_id ps aux` will show that the Jenkins process is being run by the `jenkins` user.